# Angular material matStepLabels does not shown at first

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-horizontal-stepper like in the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples).
But there is a problem I could not figure out.The mat-step labels that I use like `<ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>` do not show the first time I open the project in the browser. 
There are no errors. When I refresh the page, step text and icon are shown.

I do not understand what the problem is. Could it be a CSS problem maybe?.

Can you please help me ?

([This is the screenshot when i open the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRjZb.png) - [and after the refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQ9L.png))

Comment: Could you please add a stackblitz of your code?

Comment: could you provide your code? StackBlitz a good way to do this

Comment: I added the screenshots when opened the page and after refresh. I dont take this problem in stackblitz.

Comment: unable to replicate this behavior - the problem may be specific to you; open developer tools, go to network tab... see if there is a delay in loading a resource which could cause this? any errors in the console? what happens if you don't do refresh and just wait it out (keeping an eye on the network tabs of the developer tools)